# android, ошибка при использование retrofit

Tags: java, android, сервер, retrofit

Стэк лист ошибки:

```
07-27 07:55:50.863 4854-4854/com.project.samuliak.psychogram E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.project.samuliak.psychogram, PID: 4854
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getAllTabsByDoctor(Ljava/lang/String;)Lretrofit2/Call; in class Lcom/project/samuliak/psychogram/API/PsychogolistAPI; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.project.samuliak.psychogram.API.PsychogolistAPI' appears in /data/data/com.project.samuliak.psychogram/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex)
   at com.project.samuliak.psychogram.Activity.main.menu.common_items.CommunicationActivity.initTab(CommunicationActivity.java:66)
   at com.project.samuliak.psychogram.Activity.main.menu.common_items.CommunicationActivity.onCreate(CommunicationActivity.java:55)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Код вызова:

```
public class CommunicationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private PsychogolistAPI service;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private Psychogolist doctor;
    private Client client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_communication);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        initTab();
    }

    private void initTab() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.HOST)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(PsychogolistAPI.class);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        Call<List<Tab>> listCall = service.getAllTabsByDoctor("www");

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        //Utils.initProgressDialog(progressDialog, this);

        assert listCall != null;
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Tab>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Tab>> call, Response<List<Tab>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
//                    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
//                            response.body());
//                    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
//                    assert tabLayout != null;
//                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
                }
                //progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Tab>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.connecting_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
```

API:

```
    // список табов по доктору
@GET("tab/doctor{name}")
Call<List<Tab>> getAllTabsByDoctor(@Path("name") String psLogin);
```

Что за проблема? Как исправить?

Comment: попробуйте сделать метод public

Comment: Если вы про метод, где исполняется код вызова - то не помогло

Comment: покажите больше кода,  покажите класс где находиться этот метод

Comment: добавил, но все равно хз поему не работает

Comment: я говорил про метод getAllTabsByDoctor, он у вас где то в другом месте переопределен!

Comment: Ну так в API. Но он там не скрыт.

Comment: Делал се как раньше, но почему то именно здесь появилась данная ошибка. Раньше такого никогда не было

Comment: Все, ошибка исправлена. Не знаю почему, но она исчезла после того, как поменял метод GET на POST. Хотя на сервере было так же ГЕТ, пришлось и там пост поставить.